# How to only show a snippet of text for a blog page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am making a website which has a blog, however I do not know how to make it so that only a snippet of text shows (say the start of the article) so that users can click on "read more" to open that particular article.

Obviously I could do this by putting the first few lines in HTML, with a "..."

and linking it to a page with the full article, using  tags etc.

But, is this the correct way?

I don't know what I should be searching for so therefore I am not finding much information, just lots of wordpress stuff and I am using bootstrap and Less.

I haven't put my code as this is just a general question, I do not have a piece of code I am needing help with, just would like to know how this is done and/or a link to a good explanation as I am pretty new to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a snippet of your page and  use it for this purpose,it will help you in seo if you can use that in meta tag too to better index your page and hence better search result will be displayed .

Comment: Great thanks, I have been optimizing it for SEO also so good to know. Thanks. So I just put my own snippet there, I don't write any code to do this? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you feel this solved your issue than please accept and vote the answer

Comment: I was waiting for a reply, and I always accept answers, new to stackoverflow but a long term user of maths stackexchange..